# GKLeaderboard.localPlayerScore returns nil on iOS 8.1.3?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I have been using `GKLeaderboard.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler` and then the `localPlayerScore` property so that I can retrieve the user's high score from `Game Center` when my game is launched.

Now on iOS `7.0` to `8.1.2`, I get a valid `GKScore` object when I access the localPlayerScore property. On iOS `8.1.3` however, I am getting nil which causes my app to crash. I get a run-time error saying it found nil while unwrapping an optional.

Here is a snippet of code relevant to the issue:

```
func compareLocalHighScoreFromLeaderboards()
{
    // This is to fetch data from the high score leaderboard
    let leaderboardRequest = GKLeaderboard()
    leaderboardRequest.identifier = GlobalVariables.sharedInstance._highScoreLeaderboardID
    leaderboardRequest.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler { (scores, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil
        {
            println("Error fetching score from leaderboards: \(error))")
        }
        else if scores != nil
        {
            println("entered loading scores from leaderboards")


            let leaderboardScore = leaderboardRequest.localPlayerScore // this returns a GKScore object

            var playerLocalHighScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(GlobalVariables.sharedInstance._highScoreKey) as NSNumber


            // Check first if the saved highscore is updated.
            if playerLocalHighScore.longLongValue != leaderboardScore.value
            {
                // this means that we don't have the updated leaderboard score in our device
                if playerLocalHighScore.longLongValue > leaderboardScore.value
                {

                    println("Local score is greater than leaderboard highscore. Do nothing because GameKit will automatically report to GC when there is internet connectivity")
                }
                else if playerLocalHighScore.longLongValue < leaderboardScore.value
                {

                    // update the local highscore with the leaderboard highscore
                    let updatedHighscore: NSNumber = NSNumber(longLong: leaderboardScore.value)
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(updatedHighscore, forKey: GlobalVariables.sharedInstance._highScoreKey)

                    // send notification message to MainMenuScene to update the SKLabelNode
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(UpdatedLocalHighScore, object: nil)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                println("The local highscore and the leaderboard highscore are already in sync")
            }


        }
    }
}
```

I have been using this same code for my previous games (which are approved and live on the Appstore by the way) to retrieve the user's game center high score and have not faced this issue until `8.1.3`.

My current app was rejected by Apple because they tested it with an iOS `8.1.3` device and it crashed. I did some debugging and found out that this `localPlayerScore` being nil is the root of the problem.

Anyone facing this issue lately? Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If a crash is caused by `localPlayerScore` being `nil`, then it's not included in this excerpt. What's in the `...`?

Comment: @mattt I edited my post to include my full method. Basically, I retrieve the player's GC high score and then compare it with the locally saved high score on the user's device to keep them both in sync. The app crashes because my leaderboardScore variable is nil. This is confusing to me because this works fine on iOS 7.0 to 8.1.2.

Comment: @aresz did you find a fix? I'm facing the same issue. If you can post it here, I'd me so much grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Change `else if scores != nil` for this `else if leaderBoardRequest.localPlayerScore != nil`, because `scores` contain all the information of `leaderboardRequest.identifier` and the first time when the user open your game, `leaderBoardRequest.localPlayerScore` is empty, but `scores` not necessarily

```
   let leaderboardRequest = GKLeaderboard()
leaderboardRequest.identifier = GlobalVariables.sharedInstance._highScoreLeaderboardID
leaderboardRequest.loadScoresWithCompletionHandler { (scores, error) -> Void in
    if error != nil
    {
        println("Error fetching score from leaderboards: \(error))")
    }
    else if leaderBoardRequest.localPlayerScore != nil
    {
        println("entered loading scores from leaderboards")


        let leaderboardScore = leaderboardRequest.localPlayerScore // this returns a GKScore object

        var playerLocalHighScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(GlobalVariables.sharedInstance._highScoreKey) as NSNumber


        // Check first if the saved highscore is updated.
        if playerLocalHighScore.longLongValue != leaderboardScore.value
        {
            // this means that we don't have the updated leaderboard score in our device
            if playerLocalHighScore.longLongValue > leaderboardScore.value
            {

                println("Local score is greater than leaderboard highscore. Do nothing because GameKit will automatically report to GC when there is internet connectivity")
            }
            else if playerLocalHighScore.longLongValue < leaderboardScore.value
            {

                // update the local highscore with the leaderboard highscore
                let updatedHighscore: NSNumber = NSNumber(longLong: leaderboardScore.value)
                NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(updatedHighscore, forKey: GlobalVariables.sharedInstance._highScoreKey)

                // send notification message to MainMenuScene to update the SKLabelNode
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(UpdatedLocalHighScore, object: nil)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            println("The local highscore and the leaderboard highscore are already in sync")
        }


    }else{
println("leaderBoardRequest.localPlayerScore is empty")}
///here report the local high score to leaderboard
}
```